# Are there any precise programs or techniques that can lesson debugging time?

Tags: php, debugging

I'm working on a small project using PHP. The project is due to be finished in about 3 weeks or so. I'm making good progress, but my work is constantly impeded by small syntax errors. I'm fully aware that this is a large part of coding, it's just that I'm running short on time and there are ***hundreds*** of lines to sift through. Does anyone know a precise program or technique that can help me debug quicker? I currently have one error stopping progress right now:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I, of course, have no idea where the issue is, just what file it's in.

Comment: Yes, write flawless code like me!  PS, I use an IDE (Eclipse PDT).  That takes care of syntax issues.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Ha, ha -_-  (I just saw the edit. It might be too late to transfer the code. I'll look into it.)

Comment: This off topic for a few reasons (which is why I voted to close it).  But I would suggest improving your editor.  There are many really good IDE's out there.  I use Eclipse PDT, because its free (and I'm cheep).  It's still a bit quirky, but it's come a long way sense the 3.1 days.  It will take care of syntax highlighting, code completion, hinting etc...   Has support for Git SVN, Composer etc.

Comment: I'm currently using Atom, maybe I should see if there are any plug-ins that might help. Also, if you have time, could you list why it's off-topic? This is my second question to be closed. I'm trying to improve what I ask.

Comment: Its off topic because it's Not about a specific programing problem, Opinion based (unanswerable), and is asking for information or resources from off SO.  For example 5 years from now maybe Eclipse PDT no longer exists so by it being off site resource the validity of the answer would be time sensitive.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Also here is a link to the SO help as to what is an on-topic question https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  A confusing on is this `software tools commonly used by programmers;` this means a specific program, for example if you had Eclipse PDT and the auto compete broke, you could ask about that, but just asking what editor should I use is off topic.  Thanks!